# How to read one .CAP file with C?

Tags: c

My code in C/C++, shoud **read some data from a .CAP** file, (by the TCPDUMP). One good example could be by WireShark, but I need realy less data.

This .CAP  seems to be writen in HEXA and, when I try to read it, the **variables are coming "codified"** ?!?!

Well, I just a newbee and I **have to learn this**, I think I am not able to make the correct question... soo, I count on friends good wills  to figure it out..

Another Issue is I am totaly lost in an ocean of links in the net... and I just get more confuses...

**Explain:**
[in this link you can get the .CAP](http://tecnocubo.com.br/downloads/foruns/tcpdump_20160712_2300.cap), That can be easyli open by WireShark.

Following, my code below... pop ups "strange caracters".

**like:**

## ==> **revision: �ò�***

OR

### ==> ***header_pad: ò�***

where "revision", for exemple shound be **12 HEXA**  or converted **18 decimal**

- Wel,  I tryed to coment the code and, this soppouse to run in linux terminal.

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// #include <curses.h>

// テスト用フラグ => Test for the flag
int LOOP_ONCE = 1;

// WiFi取得情報構造体 => get information structure

// Radiotap Header
// 18bytes固定長（と思われる）=> fixed length (seems to be)
typedef struct WF_HEADER
{
    char header_revision[1];
  char header_pad[1];
  unsigned short int header_length;
  char present_flags[4];
  char flags[1];
  char data_rate[1];
  char channel_frequency[2];
  char channel_flags[2];
  char ssi_signal[1];
  char antenna[1];
  char rx_flags[2];
} wf_header_t;

// IEEE802.11 Probe Request （前半部分）=>  (first half)
// 24bytes固定長  =>  fixed length
typedef struct WF_PROBE1
{
  char frame_control_field[4];
  char receiver_address[6];
  char transmitter_address[6];
  char bbs_id[6];
  char numbers[2];
} wf_probe1_t;

// IEEE802.11 Probe Request（後半部分）=>  (the latter part)
// 4bytes固定長 => fixed length
typedef struct WF_PROBE2
{
  char frame_check_sequence[4];
} wf_probe2_t;

// IEEE802.11 wireless LAN management frame（繰り返しヘッダー） => (repeat header)
// 2bytes
typedef struct WF_MANAGE_HEADER
{
  char tag_number[1];
  char tag_length[1];
} wf_manage_header_t;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char read_fname[30]; //読み込みファイル名                => read file name
  int read_fb;         //読み込みファイルバンドル           => read file bundle
  wf_header_t *wfh;    //WiFiデータ読み込み構造体のポインタ  => pointer of WiFi data read structure
  int read_size;       //読み込みファイルサイズ             => read file size
  int wfh_size;        // Wifiデータ構造体のサイズ          => Wifi data structure; int wfh_size

  /* WiFiデータ読み込み構造体の領域確保      =>   Area of ​​WiFi data read structure ensure */
  wfh_size = sizeof(wf_header_t);
  wfh = calloc(1, wfh_size);

  /* ループ実行 */ 
  /* Loop execution */
  while (1) {
    /* ファイルの存在を監視する         =>  To monitor the presence of the file */
    /* 読み込みファイル名取得      =>  Read file name acquisition */
    if (1) {

        system("clear");

        // テスト用プログラム            =>  Test program
      fprintf(stdout, "読み込みファイル名を入力してください。\n"); // Please enter the reading file name 
      scanf("%s", read_fname);
      fprintf(stdout, "ファイル名:%s\n", read_fname);         //file name:
    } else {
      // 次のファイル名を取得するような仕組み   =>  Like to get the following file name mechanism


    }
    /* ファイルオープン処理     =>  Seek to the data top position */
    read_fb = open(read_fname, O_RDONLY);
    if (read_fb == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイルオープンに失敗しました。\n"); //Failed to open file
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイル名：%s\n", read_fname);    //file name
      return -1;
    }

    /* データ先頭位置までシークする                           =>  Seek to the data top position * /
    /* 前ファイルの続きである場合は、そのまま残サイズを読み込む    => Case is a continuation of the previous file, as it is read in the remaining size */

    read_size = read(read_fb, wfh, wfh_size);
    if (read_size == -1) {
      /* ファイル読み込み失敗       =>     File read failure */
      free(wfh); 
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイル読み込みに失敗しました。\n");  //failed to file read
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイル名：%s\n", read_fname);    //file name
      return -1;
    } else if (read_size == wfh_size) {
      fprintf(stdout, "====================================\n");
      fprintf(stdout, "revision: %s \n", wfh->header_revision);
      fprintf(stdout, "header_pad: %s \n", wfh->header_pad);
      fprintf(stdout, "present_flags: %s \n", wfh->present_flags);
      fprintf(stdout, "flags: %s \n", wfh->flags);
      fprintf(stdout, "data_rate: %s \n", wfh->data_rate);
      fprintf(stdout, "channel_frequency: %s \n", wfh->channel_frequency);
      fprintf(stdout, "channel_flags: %s \n", wfh->channel_flags);
      fprintf(stdout, "ssi_signal: %s \n", wfh->ssi_signal);
      fprintf(stdout, "antenna: %s \n", wfh->antenna);
      fprintf(stdout, "rx_flags: %s \n", wfh->rx_flags);
      fprintf(stdout, "====================================\n");



    } else {
      /* 残りサイズを読み込み、次のファイルへ進む    => Read the remaining size, advance to the next file */


    }


    /* 終了処理   End processing */
    if (close(read_fb) != -1) {
      // ファイルクローズに成功したので、バックアップフォルダへ移動させる
      // Since successful file close, move to the backup folder

    } else {
      free(wfh); 
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイルクローズに失敗しました。\n"); // file close failed 
      fprintf(stderr, "ファイル名：%s\n", read_fname);    // file name
      return -1;
    }
    /* ループ終了判定    =>    Loop termination determination */
    if (LOOP_ONCE == 1) {
      free(wfh); 
      fprintf(stdout, "終了しました。\n"); // was completed
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for all tips an help ! !

Answer (score 1):

You do know that in C a string is a sequence of characters terminated by the special character `'\0'`?

If you print a single character as a string, the `printf` function will loop printing characters until it finds the terminator character, and that will be beyond the limits of your one-character arrays. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

The simple solution is to not use arrays for structure members that are not really arrays (I mean all those one-element arrays). And then to use the proper `printf` format conversion specifier to print the characters. The correct specifier is either `"%c"` if you want to print it as a character, or `"%hhd"` if you want to print it as a small integer number.

For more information about the `printf` format specifiers, please read e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 1):

To read .cap files, you use one of available libraries which will parse the file into individual packets. Do not call read() on the file directly.